# How to get filter mongodb documents based on only dates, but not timestamps?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm working on a functionality where I need to get mongodb documents stored between dates.

I don't want to compare timestamps at all to get the data.

Here is the sample data I have.

**Sample Data:**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fb266103d41cc0a686b02e8"),
    "projectId" : "80674480738",
    "hum" : 20,
    "temp" : 40,
    "deviceId" : "DEV-1",
    "entryDayTime" : ISODate("2020-11-16T11:44:16.443Z")
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fb265fda153fb1a446bff4a"),
    "projectId" : "80674480738",
    "hum" : 20,
    "temp" : 40,
    "deviceId" : "DEV-1",
    "entryDayTime" : ISODate("2020-11-16T11:43:57.148Z")
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fb26599e876dc2428f54ca4"),
    "projectId" : "80674480738",
    "hum" : 20,
    "temp" : 40,
    "deviceId" : "DEV-1",
    "entryDayTime" : ISODate("2020-11-14T11:42:17.629Z")
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fb265616151552660d3799f"),
    "projectId" : "80674480738",
    "hum" : 20,
    "temp" : 40,
    "deviceId" : "DEV-1",
    "entryDayTime" : ISODate("2020-11-14T11:41:21.590Z")
}
```

Now I want to get the documents stored on `11-14-2020 (mm-dd-yyyy format)`.

Following is the query I'm using.

**Query:**

```
mongoose.connection.db.collection('80674480738')
                                    .aggregate([
                                        {
                                            $match: {
                                                "entryDayTime": {
                                                    $lte: "2020-11-14T18:30:00.000Z",
                                                    $gte: "2020-11-14T18:30:00.000Z"
                                                }
                                            }
                                        },{
                                            $sort:{"_id":-1}
                                        }
                                    ]).toArray();
```

**Expected result:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fb26599e876dc2428f54ca4"),
    "projectId" : "80674480738",
    "hum" : 20,
    "temp" : 40,
    "deviceId" : "DEV-1",
    "entryDayTime" : ISODate("2020-11-14T11:42:17.629Z")
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fb265616151552660d3799f"),
    "projectId" : "80674480738",
    "hum" : 20,
    "temp" : 40,
    "deviceId" : "DEV-1",
    "entryDayTime" : ISODate("2020-11-14T11:41:21.590Z")
}
```

By using the above query, am not getting the result.
After debugging the code I found that the conflict is because of the timestamps.

So now I want to only compare `dates but not timestamps` to get the result.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Condition `"entryDayTime": { $lte: "2020-11-14T18:30:00.000Z", $gte: "2020-11-14T18:30:00.000Z" }` means you select document **exactly** and only at `"2020-11-14T18:30:00.000Z"`

Try

```
{
   $match: {
      "entryDayTime": {
          $lte: ISODate("2020-11-14T23:59:59.999Z"),
          $gte: ISODate("2020-11-14T00:00:00.000Z")
       }
   }
}
```

Or you could use the [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/) library:

```
{
   $match: {
      "entryDayTime": {
          $lte: moment("2020-11-14T18:30:00.000Z").endOf('day').toDate(),
          $gte: moment("2020-11-14T18:30:00.000Z").startOf('day').toDate()
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: I have tried the 2nd approach but no result is returned and the timestamps are looking same, @Wernfried Domscheit

Comment: Is it impossible to search based on only dates?

Comment: This is the values I have printed on console, ```entryDayTime: { '$lte': 2020-11-15T18:30:00.000Z, '$gte': 2020-11-15T18:30:00.000Z  }```

Comment: `"2020-11-15T18:30:00.000Z"` is a **string** - you must compare `Date` objects with **Date** values.

Comment: You mean `$lte: moment("2020-11-14").endOf('day').toDate(), $gte: moment("2020-11-14").startOf('day').toDate()`?

Comment: Yes, i want to compare the dates

Comment: Then simply do it.

Comment: You mean to say that, if I use this, ```$lte: moment("2020-11-14").endOf('day').toDate(), $gte: moment("2020-11-14").startOf('day').toDate()``` can I get the expected result @Wernfried Domscheit?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224753/discussion-between-aravind-and-wernfried-domscheit).

Answer (score 1):

This might be an exotic way, but should work

```
.aggregate([
  { 
    "$set": {
      "entryDate": { 
        "$toDate": {
          "$subtract": [
            { "$toLong": "$entryDayTime" },
            { "$mod": [ { "$toLong": "$entryDayTime" }, 86400 * 1000] }
          ]
        }
      }
    } 
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "entryDate": ISODate("2020-11-14")
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "_id": 1
    }
  }
]);
```

The first stage will create a new `entryDate` field.

The second stage will filter those records that have matching `entryDate`.

The third stage will sort records by `_id`.

It's not that light as the below query but should work.

```
.find({
  "entryDayTime": {
    "$gte": ISODate("2020-11-14"),
    "$lt": ISODate("2020-11-15")
  }
}).sort({
  "_id": 1
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Andrew Unclear. So does the 2nd approach also work? Or should I go with the 1st one to compare with only dates?

Comment: @Aravind both work works for me. I would use the first one only if I need to add more aggregation stages.